# Susy 2 Framework for SASS undefined mixin ' span'

Tags: sass, susy-sass

I am having a small issue using Susy in that it seems to be using the old syntax.

I have the latest version of SASS (3.3.6). I have the latest version of SUSY (2.1.2). I have the latest version of Codekit (1.9.3).

I have included this in my global.rb file:

```
require "susy";
```

I have also imported this as below:

```
@import 'susy';
```

So everything should be fine. Using standard variables for the setup I have added the following code to a simple div block:

```
@include span(5);
```

Which should span the block 5 columns out of 10. Simple enough but I get an error:

```
Undefined mixin 'span'
```

Correct me if I am wrong but is this not the new syntax, as shown here:

http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/

If I use this:

```
@include span-columns(5 omega);
```

Everything is fine. But this is using the old syntax for Susy One.  Am I missing the obvious here? I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Try uninstalling Susy and see if there's an old version there. Maybe that's being importet and not Susy 2.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling compass, sass, susy and have reinstalled the gems. This is the error I am getting back:

**WARNING: Something went horribly wrong here. Try adjusting your variables.
         on line 104 of /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/susy/sass/susy/_media.scss, in `at-breakpoint'
         from line 83 of /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/susy/sass/susy/_grid.scss, in `container'
         from line 16 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trevorsaint.dev/scss/global.scss**

Comment: That error is part of Susy 1, as is `span-columns`. If you are getting that error, you are not actually importing Susy 2.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of uinstalling gems and reinstalling gems I was able to get things working.

I used the following:

**sudo gem uninstall compass 

sudo gem install compass --pre**

This seems to have fixed the problem for me.

So these are the gems I have installed:

**Compass (1.0.0.alpha.19)

Sass (3.3.8, 3.2.19)

Susy (2.1.2)**

Comment: You should accept your answer as correct if it fixed it.